# Una de las partes con la que intentas hacer el pago es de prueba

Tags: nodejs, express, mercadopago

Estoy implementando el checkout pro de mercadopago con la documentación que ofrecen en su página oficial. Estoy haciendo los pasos que voy a detallar a continuación:

1. Creo dos usuarios con la API que ofrecen (uno cliente otro vendedor)
2. Seteo el access token de prueba (del usuario de prueba que tengo como vendedor) en el backend
3. Hago una consulta a mi endpoint del backend y me devuelve el initPoint y el sandboxInitPoint
4. Accedo a cualquiera de esos, pongo los datos de las tarjetas de prueba que ofrecen o me registro con el usuario de prueba de cliente
5. Me arroja el error detallado en el titulo

Este es mi codigo del backend

```
require('dotenv').config()
const mercadopago = require("mercadopago");

mercadopago.configure({
  access_token: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_MP
});

const createPreference = async (req, res) => {
  let preference = {
    items: [
      {
        title: req.body.description,
        unit_price: Number(req.body.price),
        quantity: Number(req.body.quantity),
      }
    ],
    back_urls: {
      "success": "http://localhost:8080/feedback",
      "failure": "http://localhost:8080/feedback",
      "pending": "http://localhost:8080/feedback"
    },
    auto_return: "approved",
  };

  try {
    const response = await mercadopago.preferences.create(preference)
    res.json({
      response
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

El access token es el del usuario de prueba que tengo como vendedor.

No vi a nadie más que le pase esto, quizás estoy haciendo algún paso mal yo, pero por la documentación y el codigo de ejemplo que ofrecen es lo que pude entender.

Si alguien me puede ayudar lo apreciaría mucho. Gracias por adelantado!

Comment: ¿Puede ser que estés usando la API de producción con datos de prueba? Sin código para revisar, todo lo que vas a recibir son suposiciones. Siéntete libre de [edit] la pregunta y añadirle info. Procura no incluir en la pregunta datos sensibles, como tokens productivos, credenciales, etc

Comment: Ahí agregue el código. Avísame si necesitas algo más, pero eso funciona, me devuelve la respuesta y entro al initPoint. Como puedo saber si estoy usando la api de prueba o de producción?

Comment: Suena a que hiciste lo que dice [la documentación](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/guides/online-payments/checkout-api/testing) pero no estás configurando correctamente el paso 1 en la prueba del flujo de pago. La public key y el access token parecen incorrectos de acuerdo a lo que indicas (si estás usando las TC de prueba y creaste los usuarios comprador y vendedor de prueba como lo indica la misma documentación)

Comment: Para crear los usuarios use el PROD_ACCESS_TOKEN de mi cuenta personal, supongo que habrá que usar ese. Despues hago la consulta tal como indica ahi y me devuelve los usuarios perfectamente. La public key dice que tengo que usarla en el frontend, pero vi el video que tienen de mercadopago en youtube y pueden hacer la prueba directamente entrando al initUrl

Comment: Bueno ya encontre el error, tenia que usar el token de produccion del usuario de prueba, a pesar de que en la pagina aparezca un warning de que estoy usando un usuario de prueba.

Comment: Ponlo como respuesta, puedes incluso aceptarlo luego para que otros con el mismo lío sepan qué hacer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acá cuando entras al usuario de prueba, a pesar del mensaje en naranja hay que poner las credenciales de producción y luego entrar al `sandboxInitUrl`

[image: Credenciales]

Comment: me sigue pasando lo mismo, lo resolviste asi?

Answer (score 4):

Para otros con este problema el procedimiento para pagos de prueba es asi:

1. Desde tu cuenta de produccion crear dos **Cuentas de Prueba**, una llamada "*Comprador*" y la otra "*Vendedor*".
2. En otro navegador ingresar a MercadoPago Developers con la cuenta *Vendedor*.
3. Crear una preferencia de pago usando el **ACCESS_TOKEN** de producción del Vendedor.
4. Ingresar al **init_point** URL de la preferencia para pagar.
5. Loguearse con el usuario *Comprador* de prueba para pagarla con tarjeta o saldo precargado en la cuenta de prueba.

Cuando se intenta pagar con tarjeta como **invitado**, sigue saltando el error de que *una de las partes con la que intentas hacer el pago es de prueba*. Esto solo puede ser un error de la API, estoy usando curl directamente, no el SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer tanto las credenciales del vendedor como las del comprador deben ser de prueba o pertenecer a cuentas de prueba, yo hice lo siguiente

Genere dos cuentas usando el ACCESS_TOKEN de Producción del cliente

curl -X POST 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' 
"https://api.mercadopago.com/users/test_user" 
-d '{"site_id":"MLA"}'

- Inicie sesión con la primera cuenta en https://www.mercadopago.com.pe/developers/ fui a integraciones y genere credenciales de prueba en mi caso son para un ecommerce Magento.
- Configure estas credenciales (public key y access_token) en el sitio
- Inicie el proceso de compra y en la ventana para iniciar sesión de MP puse el email y el password de la segunda cuenta, es importante que sea el de la segunda cuenta porque sino saldrá un error de "no te puedes comprar a ti mismo".

Y listo haciendo esto pude probar el flujo de compra completo.

Comment: Algo parecido hice yo, con la diferencia que usé las credenciales PRODUCCION del vendedor de prueba, no las de SANDBOX, para generar la preferencia de pago.